# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have create one demo which is based on mashape api call.But I get error.I tried lots of suggestion.but not get any solution.

**java Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new CallMashapeAsync().execute();


    }

    private class CallMashapeAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, HttpResponse<JsonNode>> {

        protected HttpResponse<JsonNode> doInBackground(String... msg) {

            HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = null;
            try {
                request = Unirest.get("https://indianpost.p.mashape.com/getOffices.php?pincode=394101")
                        .header("X-Mashape-Key", "My API")
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .asJson();
            } catch (UnirestException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return request;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...integers) {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse<JsonNode> response) {
            String answer = response.getBody().toString();
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            txtView.setText(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hungama3.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mashape-java-client-2.0.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/unirest-java-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar')
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:459)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:41)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:27)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:121)
            at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:64)
            at com.example.hungama3.myapplication.MainActivity$CallMashapeAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
            at com.example.hungama3.myapplication.MainActivity$CallMashapeAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I tried lots of jar file for http apache library but not getting any solution.
If any one have any suggestion then tell me.

Error focus line 37 which is indicate "request" in try catch.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit again:**

After second thought, actually android's library contains httpclient already (pre android 6.0), you including it yourself, you could be creating a conflict. Try simply remove the jar and try.

remove the line

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar')
```

You may need to remove this as well

```
compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar')
```

Comment: I changed line compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6' but same error getting now ....

Comment: check my edit, its probably because android has its own httpclient already

Comment: remove the line in build.gradle. Please check my updated answer

Comment: ic, this is a problem with android. You can check this

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

but you would still need to modify unirest-java by yourself

Comment: https://github.com/zeeshanejaz/unirest-android, this maybe useful as well. P.S. I haven't tried it myself

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to add HttpComponents as a dependency? Not sure if you need to include HttpClient like you did, android already includes it.

Comment: Try dereks full solution, I agree with him that you don't need httpclient

Answer (score 0):

For android remove all httpclient and httpcore dependencies and add

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'    // gradle depedencies
```

in your build.gradle file. You wil get rid of all the issues as android already has httpclient and httpcore libraries with it.